# How to subtract columns from two different tables in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to DAX funciton on Power BI. I have two tables as Parent table Dim_TargetSpec and Child table Fact_Yield. These tables have relationship via Spec column. I want to substract by Dim_TargetSpec[Target_Fat] - Fact_Yield[Average Fat] and this is the DAX function

```
Fat_Diff = Dim_TargetSpec[Target_Fat] - LOOKUPVALUE(Fact_YieldReport[Average Fat],Fact_YieldReport[Spec], Dim_TargetSpec[Spec],0)
```

This function returns unexpected results exactly the Dim_TargetSpec[Target_Fat] column:

```
    Spec    Target_Fat  Average_Fat   Fat_Diff
    AFC_2   15.2        14.2          15.2
    AFC_2   15.5        16.00         15.5
```

My expected correct results are:

```
Spec    Target_Fat  Average_Fat   Fat_Diff
AFC_2   15.2        14.2           1.0
AFC_2   15.5        16.0          -0.5
```

Could anyone please help me to correct the DAX function so getting correct results?

Much appreciated for your help
Thanks

Comment: Why you cannot substract the "Average_Fat" value directly ?

Comment: I want to add new column " Fat_Diff" on Dim_TargetSpec table, while Average_Fat is on Fact_Yield table, so that why I cann't substract the "Average_Fat" value directly

Comment: Did you try `lookup` or `calculate` so that it will return the value on "Average_fat" column, after that you can substract value with directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
DiffColumn=Dim_TargetSpec[Target_Fat] - RELATED(Fact_Yield[Average Fat])
```

Comment: Hi smpa01,   as your function, I have tried to add the new column DiffColumn on Dim_TargetSpec, but it says that Fact_Yield[Average Fat] doesn't exist, although they have relationship 1 to many

Comment: please post sample data representative of the issue.

Comment: Hi smpa01, the sample data is in my question, or can you please elaborate "sample data representative of the issue"?

Comment: If you apply my solution to the sample data you would get what you were hoping for. Cause I built my answer based on what you gave here. But if you don't, it means the sample data is not representative of your issue. Hence, provide something that is representative of your issue.